# How to paste a line break into the find box

Tags: line-breaking

This is a very, very simple question, but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere.

I pasted a document from Word into TeXnicCenter.  The tabs copied over nicely, and I can paste those into the find feature, and it works just fine.  What I want to do is replace all of the tabs with line breaks.

However, for the life of me I can't figure out how to put a line break (like just hitting the enter key) in the "Replace with" box.  I want to avoid code like \newline.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you on linux ? If so I can make you a bash script for that. Could you also provide an portion of text before and after transformation ?

Answer (score 1):

The escape sequence for a line break is usually `\r` or `\n`, sometimes `\r\n` (details are [complicated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)). Some editors support typing these escape sequences into the search/replace box (I'm not sure about TeXnicCenter). If that does not work, you will need to use a different editor for this step. For example, [geany](http://www.geany.org/) is a free and lightweight editor that has sophisticated search/replace functionality. Ticking the checkbox 'use escape sequences' inside geany's search/replace dialog will allow you to use `\r` or `\n` in the replace box.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm downloading geany now.  I find it interesting that you can't just paste a line break...